# Validating A Custom Rule After Validation Passes

Tags: laravel

I'm attempting to run a custom validation rule after all other validation has passes inside the rules of my form request class. I have not included the whole form request class for brevity. I'm not sure if I should be instantiating a new instance of the rule or just calling a validate method inside the closure of the after method so that it can validate just rule.

Depending on the best path I'm not trying to validate a specific field. I'm trying to validate the sum of two fields.

Has anyone accomplished this before?

```
/**
 * Configure the validator instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 */
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $result = (new TeamHasEnoughMembers(
            $this->input('coaches'),
            $this->input('players')
        ))->passes(null, null);

        if (! $result) {
            $validator->errors()->add('coaches', 'There is not enough members.');
            $validator->errors()->add('players', 'There is not enough members.');
        }
    });
}
```

Custom Rule

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class TeamHasEnoughMembers implements Rule
{
    private ?array $coachIds = [];
    private ?array $playerIds = [];

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(?array $coachIds, ?array $playerIds)
    {
        $this->coachIds = $coachIds;
        $this->playerIds = $playerIds;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $coachesCount = count($this->coachIds);
        $playersCount = count($this->playerIds);

        if ($coachesCount >= 2) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($playersCount >= 3) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($coachesCount == 1 && $playersCount >= 1) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'There is not enough members for this team.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not make your custom validation rule fail on no input or bad input and avoid using it in a sequence, that seems like a wrong approach for an validation. Secondly couldn't that just be an if condition throw an error and handle that error in the front end?

Comment: Why don't you just put the rule on the `coaches` or `players` field?